# How to get the Stack trace when logging exceptions with NLog?

Tags: .net, exception, stack-trace, nlog

When I use the default layout with NLog it only prints the name of the exception.
I've been told that the log4jxmlevent layout doesn't prints nothing about the exception.
What layout will help me?

Example code:

```
try
{
    throw new SystemException();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error("oi", ex);
}
```

Default layout output:

```
2011-01-14 09:14:48.0343|ERROR|ConsoleApplication.Program|oi
```

log4jxmlevent output:

```
<log4j:event logger="ConsoleApplication.Program"
           level="ERROR"
           timestamp="1295003776872"
           thread="9">
<log4j:message>oi</log4j:message>
<log4j:NDC />
<log4j:locationInfo class="ConsoleApplication.Program"
                    method="Void Main(System.String[])"
                    file="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication\Program.cs"
                    line="21" />
<nlog:eventSequenceNumber>3</nlog:eventSequenceNumber>
<nlog:locationInfo assembly="ConsoleApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<log4j:properties>
  <log4j:data name="log4japp"
              value="true" />
  <log4j:data name="log4jmachinename"
              value="MACHINE" />
</log4j:properties>
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As documented in [How to Log Exceptions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions), starting with NLog 4.0, pass the exception as the first parameter to `Error`, for example like this:

```
logger.Error(ex, "ex");
```

and a custom layout

```
layout="${exception:format=ToString}${newline}"
```

Comment: Is this in addition to an existing layout?

Comment: @Shane surely, unless you only need the stack trace

Comment: FYI, this approach is deprecated. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions

Comment: Explaining the comment of @Clay: The logging line is now changed to `logger.Error("Got exception.", ex);` but the 'custom layout' is fine

Comment: Note that usage of both `ToString` and `StackTrace` cause stacktrace duplication in log output. `${exception:format=ToString}` would be enough

Comment: @JaderDias this answer is very confusing.  Can you please correct the answer or flag the comments for delete (as obsolete).

Comment: Thanks for your help in resolving this issue. I used the NLog 5.0 solution `layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:withexception=true}"`. I wonder why the developers of NLog thought it would be a good idea not to log exceptions by default given that they have been explicitly passed to the logger.

Answer (score 25):

Use the overloads that take an Exception as the second argument:

```
catch(Exception crap)
{
    log.Error(crap, "Something went horribly wrong.");
}
```

Then in your layout include the `${exception}` layout renderer:

```
<target ...
    layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}" />
```

---

Sources:

- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions
- https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 22):

As documented in [How to Log Exceptions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions), starting with NLog 4.0, pass the exception as the first parameter to `Error`, for example like this:

```
logger.Error(ex, "Nickers!");
```

In the NLog configuration (e.g. in `web.config` or `app.config`), include `${exception:format=tostring}` in the layout, for example like this:

```
<target name="f" type="File" layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

Comment: Can use [Conditional Formatting](http://nlog-project.org/2011/04/20/exception-logging-enhancements.html) in the layout for exceptions. The following is close to the default layout `<target name="f" type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}${onexception:${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}"/>`.

Answer (score 12):

As of NLog 4.5 you can now use:

`logger.Error(exception, message);`

and layout as follows:

`"${longdate} ${level} ${message} ${exception:format=@}"`

The `@` means serialize all Exception-properties into Json-format

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for - gets full Json version of the Exception in the logs rather than just Exception type and message